# How to get $this->request->getAttribute('csrfToken') from Helper in Cakephp4?

Tags: php, cakephp-4.x

I need to get **csrf token from a Helper** to use it in an ajax request.

But when I try to get it using :

```
<?= $this->request->getAttribute('csrfToken') ?>
```

`$this->request` is null from the helper.

Someone to tell me how to do please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers do not receive the request instance, but the view instance which they are attached to, so you can obtain the request from there.

```php
$this->getView()->getRequest()->getAttribute('csrfToken')
```